# hidden division is not appearing after operating click event for dynamic table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am fetching data to a table from mysql database using php and jquery. But I want to keep the "details" column hidden, which I want should be slide down(appear ) in the corresponding table row after clicking a button named "show details". The following Image may clear my thought:

[image]

The jquery Code I am using for slide down is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#get_details").click(function(){
        $("#get_details_button").slideToggle("slow");
      });
  });
```

The code I am using to fetch data is :

```
$sub_array = array();
$sub_array[] = $row["id"];
$sub_array[] = $row["product_name"].'<p id="get_details">'.$row["details"].'</p>';
$sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="get_details_button" id="get_details_button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs get_details_button">Get Details</button>';
$data[] = $sub_array;
}
```

Please feel free to ask for any additional code if you need.

the html part is here :

```
            <table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                 <thead>
                  <tr>
                   <th width="30%">Image</th>
                   <th width="50%">Product Name</th>
                   <th width="20%">get Details</th>
                  </tr>
                 </thead>
              </table>
```

Comment: show html as well.

Comment: ok wait a min, I am editing at the question

Comment: You're generating invalid HTML. Every button has the same `id` and `name`, both of which should be unique.

Comment: well, I suspected that, can you kindly show me how can I call dynamic id in Jquery code (using for slide down )

Comment: You don't need an id to make this work. Give the buttons a class and then search by parent/children/siblings.

Comment: Thanks for your point and time. The problem is solved and I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `class` for `p` tag then whenever button is clicked use `$(this).closest('tr').find(".get_details")` to get `p` tag and show/hide same

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //onclick of button
  $(".get_details_button").click(function() {
    //get p tag and show/hide it
    $(this).closest('tr').find(".get_details").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.get_details {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="30%">Image</th>
      <th width="50%">Product Name</th>
      <th width="20%">get Details</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>1
    </td>
    <td>Soemthig,,
      <!--use class-->
      <p class="get_details">Soemthing.....</p>
    </td>
    <td><button type="button" name="get_details_button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs get_details_button">Get Details</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2
    </td>
    <td>Soemthig,,2
      <p class="get_details">Soemthing2.....</p>
    </td>
    <td><button type="button" name="get_details_button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs get_details_button">Get Details</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any ids to make this work. I don't know your markup but here is an example. You will need to work it out for your markup.

```
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ id }}</td>
      <td>{{ product_name }}</td>
      <td><button>details</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="product-details" style="display:none">...</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ id }}</td>
      <td>{{ product_name }}</td>
      <td><button>details</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="product-details" style="display:none">...</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ id }}</td>
      <td>{{ product_name }}</td>
      <td><button>details</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="product-details" style="display:none">...</div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('.container').find('button').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.product-details').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, both answers worked, but I have to choose one answer as accepted lol .so I marked accepted  the first one